# Execute a code only one time in C

Tags: c, ucos

I want execute a code only one time. I used a solution based on a global varibale of bool type. My question, is it the best solution?

Remark: I use ucos-II.

```
if (TRUE == Lock)
{
 /*Code to execute one time*/
}

/*The reste of the code*/
```

Comment: Any code will execute one time if it is not inside a loop, recursion or function called several times.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think OP is considering a _part_ of a function which can be called multiple times.

Comment: So, can we get a clarification? Anyway, having a flag for an indication is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: This is a horrible requirement.  It would be even more difficult to define/implement in multithreaded apps:)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This part of the code is inside a function which will be executed each cycle (Task).

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use a static or global. I would pass it as a parameter.

Comment: This part of code shall be executed just in startup then it is not applicable (like a dead code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple code using a static variable.

```
static bool once = false;

if (once == false)
{
    once = true;
    // do your "once" stuff here
}
```

Comment: Why exactly a static variable ?

Comment: @StackOver, A static variable lives as long as program runs. Therefore, you are sure this code is executed once in a single thread environment.

Comment: Also a global variable lives as long as program runs?

Comment: Exact but static variables can be scoped to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on when you want to do this check and where.

Let's say you have a API like

```
void func(bool flag)
{
   if(flag)
   {
      // Code for only one condition
   }
   else
   {
     //Rest of the code
   }
}
```

Then just by passing TRUE or FALSE you can make sure that the required code is executed only once.

Else your approach of having a global variable is also ok but you have to unset your `LOCK` once the required block is executed

```
if( LOCK == TRUE)
{
   //Execute code
   LOCK = FALSE;
}
```

Hope you have a global variable `LOCK` initialized to `1`.

NOTE:

> If you are on a flat memory systems it is always dangerous to have
>   global variables so we tend to avoid it. If there is a real need then
>   yes we go for global variable else we can use some flag as suggested
>   in my first approach

Answer (score 1):

So if you just use

```
if (TRUE == Lock)
{
 /*Code to execute one time*/``
}
```

Lock will ever be true rigth ?

so you need to do

```
if(Lock == TRUE)
{//code to execute
 Lock = FALSE;
}
```